# Display information text below the open file tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing an VSIX extension for Visual Studio 2019 and I want to display some "information text" to the user. I really like the way that auto-format displays them.

[image]

Now, how would I create such an window. I would hope that it is just a matter of something like `Message.DisplayInfo()` or whatever. Anyhow I would rather think that you'd need to create a new Window, if this is the case, how would I get it's Guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Infobars](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/extensibility/ux-guidelines/notifications-and-progress-for-visual-studio.md#BKMK_Infobars) documentation when it is appropriate to use and how to implement. This **Notifications and Progress for Visual Studio** document also lists other options.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!